# Twisted chainDeferred, deferred.result is None

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to chain deferreds:

```
def getDeferred1():
    d1 = defer.Deferred()
    d1.addCallback(printx)
    return d1

def getDeferred2():
    d2 = defer.Deferred()
    d2.addCallback(printy)
    return d2

def printx(x):
    print 'printx', x
    return x

def printy(y):
    print 'printy', y
    return y

d = getDeferred1()
d2 = getDeferred2()
# d.chainDeferred(d2)    #1
# d.addCallback(printy)  #2

d.callback('RESULT')
print 'Result', d.result
```

The curent code will print:

```
printx RESULT
Result RESULT
```

But if I uncomment line #1, to chain `d2` to `d`, `d.result` will be `None`:

```
printx RESULT
printy RESULT
Result None
```

How to obtain `deferred.result` not `None` when chaining another deferred ?

Answer (score 2):

It is usually not necessary to use `chainDeferred` explicitly.  Deferreds are chained together automatically when one is returned from a callback on another.

It is basically always wrong to use `Deferred.result` directly.  The way you get the result of a Deferred is by adding a callback to the Deferred.  When the Deferred has a result, the callback will be called with it.

It's not idiomatic to separate the creation and the calling-back of a Deferred as is done in your sample code.  `getDeferred1` is creating the Deferred that this code eventually calls back.  It would be idiomatic for `getDeferred1` to be responsible for the eventual `d.callback` call.

Since this code is abstract and non-idiomatic, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.  The only advice I can give is that you probably don't need `chainDeferred` and you definitely shouldn't write code that accesses `Deferred.result`.